# multiple files combination in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Assume the file1 is:

```
     State        Date      
0    NSW        01/02/16
1    NSW        01/03/16
3    VIC        01/04/16
...
100 TAS          01/12/17
```

File 2 is:

```
    State      01/02/16  01/03/16  01/04/16  ....   01/12/17
0     VIC        10000      12000     14000  ....      17600
1     NSW        50000
....
```

Now I would like to join these two files based on Date
In the other words, I want to combine the file1's Date column with file2 columns' date.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), parameter `on` is possible omit for merge by all columns same in both `DataFrame`s:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2)

df = df2.melt('State', var_name='Date', value_name='col').merge(df1, how='right')
print (df)
  State      Date      col
0   NSW  01/02/16  50000.0
1   NSW  01/03/16      NaN
2   VIC  01/04/16  14000.0
3   TAS  01/12/17      NaN
```

Solution with `left` join:

```
df = df1.merge(df2.melt('State', var_name='Date', value_name='col'), how='left')
print (df)
  State      Date      col
0   NSW  01/02/16  50000.0
1   NSW  01/03/16      NaN
2   VIC  01/04/16  14000.0
3   TAS  01/12/17      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `melt` the second data frame to a long format, then `merge` with first data frame to get the values.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['NSW','NSW','VIC'], 
                    'Date': ['01/02/16', '01/03/16', '01/04/16']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['VIC',10000,12000,14000], 
                    ['NSW',50000,60000,62000]], 
                    columns=['State', '01/02/16', '01/03/16', '01/04/16'])

df1.merge(pd.melt(df2, id_vars=['State'], var_name='Date'), on=['State', 'Date'])
# returns:
       Date State  value
0  01/02/16   NSW  50000
1  01/03/16   NSW  60000
2  01/04/16   VIC  14000
```